# Hiding buttons and Enable Another with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page that I display a modal 2 button a confirmation and another cancellation, as the below code: Within this modal have a DIV `<div class = "resp"> </ div>` This div I get a response from a page in **PHP**, I would hide the 2 buttons I have inside this modal and after receiving the response from the php page show another button to close this modal. How can I do this?

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="md-default" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button " class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="text-center">
               <div class="i-circle primary"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div>
               <h4>Confirma o envio?</h4>
               <div class="resp"></div>
               <p></p>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat enviar" >Sim</button>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-content -->
   </div>
   <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

My Ajax

```
<script>
     $('.formulario').submit(function() {
         var form_data = new FormData();
         form_data.append('fileUploadAudio', $('input.fileUploadAudio').prop('files')[0]);
         form_data.append('titulo', $('input.titulo').val());
         form_data.append('mensagem', $('textarea.mensagem').val());
         form_data.append('tipo_notificacao', $('input.tipo_notificacao').val());
         $.ajax({
             url: 'postar.php', // caminho para o script que vai processar os dados
             type: 'POST',
             data: form_data,
             cache: false,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,
             success: function(response) {
                 $('.resp').html(response);
             },
             error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                 alert(xhr.responseText);
             }
         });
         return false;
     });
  </script>
```

**My page in operation**
[LINK](http://williamvillar.com.br/Push_Novo/msg_simple_text.php)

Comment: show your full code

Comment: Hello friend, I put the code and put the page up and running.

Comment: You want to hide these two buttons and want to add new button in place of these.

Comment: That's right! When you receive the ajax response hide the 2 buttons and features again to close the modal.

Answer (score 1):

First give some `id` to these two `buttons` like

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat" data-dismiss="modal" id="cancelButton">Cancelar</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat enviar" id="submitButton">Sim</button>
```

Then after we will hide these `buttons` in success function and add new `button` for close(change the HTML of close `button` your according).

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'postar.php', // caminho para o script que vai processar os dados
   type: 'POST',
   data: form_data,
   cache: false,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false,
   success: function(response) {

       closeButton = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat" data-dismiss="modal" id = "closeButton">Close</button>'
       $('#cancelButton').hide();
       $('#submitButton').hide();
       $('.resp').html(response);
       $('.modal-footer').append(closeButton);
   },
   error: function(xhr, status, error) {
       alert(xhr.responseText);
   }
});
```

Comment: Hello Sunil, I did as you said the two buttons are gone but the button that Ajax should put're not putting. Go up the ftp if you want to check the link is in my question.

Comment: It worked friend, now I only have a problem when it click this new button is how I get back to doing the show 2 of old buttons?

Comment: In what condition you want to show these two buttons back

Comment: When I click this new button again to cancel it must close the modal and when reopen the modal will appear again the two buttons.

Comment: can help me on this?